# Firefox Addon sdk - Is there a way to bypass/broke ajax request limitation in content script

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I read that in firefox addon sdk it isn't possible to emit ajax request from content script and that in that case (want to do a request), we have to do this since main.js.

Is there a way to bypass/broke sdk request limitation and enable us to complete ajax request  since content script especially to be able to use jquery extensions (like jstree) where we use ajax request and also be able to use dynamic URL?

I don't want to modify the js code of the jquery extensions

Comment: Have you tried creating an XHR from a content script? I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: For the js code that I make it seems to be a solution. The problem is that I use jquery extensions (like jstree) where there is ajax call in js code and I don't want to modify the jquery js extension. So how can do to make the jquery extension ajax call work

Comment: I tried with XHR add it don't work

Comment: You can create `XHR`s in background scripts too using `const { XMLHttpRequest } = require("sdk/net/xhr");` See [the code behind the request module](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/request.js) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do cross-domain requests from content scripts, but you need to set a permission in package.json for this to work correctly, like this:

```
"permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["http://example.org/", "http://example.com/"]
}
```

See [the docs for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts).

Comment: I think taht this solution don't work with dynamic URL as we can't use regex to define URL permissions. Isn't it? another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as you read in the Addon SDK documentation, this limitation is done for security reasons. So you have to use the `port`/`emit` functions [as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on) in order to do the AJAX request in the addon to send the result to a content script.

Comment: Yes I known this, that why I ask the question. I can't undestand that I have to fork all my jquery extension which use ajax to can use them in sdk addons as content script.  I hope that there is a better solution that some one can give me. Please help :(